AWS IAM User - Trying to Create multiple user using CSV file
This is my cloud assignment and I am getting error on 5th step.

Create five user groups named as below and give the relevant access to the groups:


CloudAdmin – admin full access
DBA – RDS full access
LinuxAdmin – EC2 full access
NetworkAdmin – VPC full access
Trainees – Read-only access


Modify the Xls file to upload as input of the user creation.

Open the cloudshell and run the command below to prepare the tool ready:


sudo yum install dos2unix -y


Download the scripts from the below address and change the permission.

wget https://sharifulbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/aws_iam_user_create.sh

chmod +x aws_iam_user_create.sh


Now, run the script and with following command:

./ aws_iam_user_create.sh users2.csv


Validate the users created from IAM->Users>Groups > permissions


Attach policy to allow users to change their passwords:
Access user groups > permission > add permission/attach policy.


Validate the user with credential change and check the user's permission.


Run ./aws_iam_user_create.sh users2.csv without a space after ./.
